# Representation of the wavelet coefficients with matlab

Tags: matlab, wavelet

I want to represent the wavelet coefficients of a 2D function using the wavelet toolbox or wavelab, but I can't manage to display a picture like this:

[image].

How do I do that?

Comment: First of all please show how what you have tried so far. A good point to start the search would be the origin of the picture. Doesn't it contain any hints like commands etc?

Comment: Doesn't such a time-scale plot correspond to a 1-D function?

Comment: They do @EitanT -- In the 1d case as above each next level is a new line, in the 2d case each of the 3 detail coefficient channels is a new image.